# C# - Integrating data (pictures) into .exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio

this is my first question here.

I've made a small quiz project about the 199 world's states via Visual Studio C#.
therefor I collected all flags of every country and put them into a folder - you can imagine that i collected MANY.

To run my current project i need the folder with all these .gif images -
otherwise the startup will end in a fatal error. :-(

My question is if it is possible to integrate the images into my .exe file so that i can run it without that nasty folder. (Also important for future project with even more content!)

And if it is possible - how?
It would also be nice if you let me know how to use the images - what pathes they have got etc ... =)

Thanks in advance!

Robbepop

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add a **resource file** to your application, by going to

> Project >> Your Project Properties >>
>   Resources >> Create A Resource File.

You can then simply add any image to your application and reference it via your code.  Select `Images` from the drop down on the top of the menu, and then click `Add Resource >> From existing file.`

After you save your resource file, you can then access your images via code, e.g.

```
> Image img =
> YourProject.Properties.Resources.Image1
```

*However*, with the number of images you have, and what I would believe you are using them for, I would suggest using a `Image List`, which you can add all of your images to, and access them via their key or index. e.g.

```
Image img = imageList1[0];
```

Or

```
Image img = imageList1["US"];
```

This can be found in your toolbox.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the images as embedded resources. Then use the ManifestResourceStream from the Assembly to extract the raw byte data, and subsequently load it as an image.

Note: this is different from the answer/approach of Femaref below.

Answer (score 3):

Every assembly in .net can contain so called resources. You can add them in the properties of a project in the resources tab. After that, you can access them via `ProjectNameSpace.Properties.Resources`.